# Configuring group access across a LAN

Tags: files, nfs, group, file-sharing

I have created a group called engineers on two VMs on the same 192.168.56.0/24 LAN. Is there any way the members from VM1 in engineers can view files created by engineers from VM2?

I was thinking of setting up a NFS server, and letting all hosts access /IT_Projects for example, but is there a way to introduce fine-grained access specific to groups?